# Foreground service stops giving location updates after 10 minutes in Oreo

Tags: android, google-play-services, background-service

I was trying to create a location service which gives location updates when app is in background specially for Android O. I tried many examples available on the internet by creating a foreground service or passing pendingIntent in requestLocationUpdates. But none of them worked. My service stops giving me location update after 10 minutes. I tried to put job scheduler also but that also doesn't work. I found the github project provided by Google [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location), but those examples are also not working.

Here is my service from one of the above example:

```
public class LocationUpdatesService extends Service {
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
            "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdatesforegroundservice";

    private static final String TAG = LocationUpdatesService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * The name of the channel for notifications.
     */
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

    static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = PACKAGE_NAME + ".broadcast";

    static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".location";
    private static final String EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION = PACKAGE_NAME +
            ".started_from_notification";

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    /**
     * The identifier for the notification displayed for the foreground service.
     */
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;

    /**
     * Used to check whether the bound activity has really gone away and not unbound as part of an
     * orientation change. We create a foreground service notification only if the former takes
     * place.
     */
    private boolean mChangingConfiguration = false;

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    /**
     * Contains parameters used by {@link com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi}.
     */
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
     */
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    /**
     * Callback for changes in location.
     */
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    private Handler mServiceHandler;

    /**
     * The current location.
     */
    private Location mLocation;

    public LocationUpdatesService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };

        createLocationRequest();
        getLastLocation();

        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
        handlerThread.start();
        mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
            // Create the channel for the notification
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
        boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
                false);

        // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
        if (startedFromNotification) {
            removeLocationUpdates();
            stopSelf();
        }
        // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mChangingConfiguration = true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) comes to the foreground
        // and binds with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground service
        // when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onBind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) returns to the foreground
        // and binds once again with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground
        // service when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onRebind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Last client unbound from service");

        // Called when the last client (MainActivity in case of this sample) unbinds from this
        // service. If this method is called due to a configuration change in MainActivity, we
        // do nothing. Otherwise, we make this service a foreground service.
        if (!mChangingConfiguration && Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting foreground service");
            /*
            // TODO(developer). If targeting O, use the following code.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mNotificationManager.startServiceInForeground(new Intent(this,
                        LocationUpdatesService.class), NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
            } else {
                startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
            }
             */
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
        return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }


    /**
     * Makes a request for location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
     * {@link SecurityException}.
     */
    public void requestLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));

        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
     * {@link SecurityException}.
     */
    public void removeLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Removing location updates");
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            stopSelf();
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link NotificationCompat} used as part of the foreground service.
     */
    private Notification getNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

        CharSequence text = Utils.getLocationText(mLocation);

        // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

        // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
        PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                        activityPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                        servicePendingIntent)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentTitle(Utils.getLocationTitle(this))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker(text)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private void getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                mLocation = task.getResult();
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
        }
    }

    private void onNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New location: " + location);

        mLocation = location;

        // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
        if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the location request parameters.
     */
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Since this service runs in the same process as its
     * clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocationUpdatesService getService() {
            return LocationUpdatesService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this is a foreground service.
     *
     * @param context The {@link Context}.
     */
    public boolean serviceIsRunningInForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (getClass().getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                if (service.foreground) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Used in checking for runtime permissions.
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    // The BroadcastReceiver used to listen from broadcasts from the service.
    private MyReceiver myReceiver;

    // A reference to the service used to get location updates.
    private LocationUpdatesService mService = null;

    // Tracks the bound state of the service.
    private boolean mBound = false;

    // UI elements.
    private Button mRequestLocationUpdatesButton;
    private Button mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton;

    // Monitors the state of the connection to the service.
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check that the user hasn't revoked permissions by going to Settings.
       // if (Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
            if (!checkPermissions()) {
                requestPermissions();
            }
       // }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        mRequestLocationUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_location_updates_button);
        mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_location_updates_button);

        mRequestLocationUpdatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!checkPermissions()) {
                    requestPermissions();
                } else {
                    mService.requestLocationUpdates();
                }
            }
        });

        mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mService.removeLocationUpdates();
            }
        });

        // Restore the state of the buttons when the activity (re)launches.
        setButtonsState(Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this));

        // Bind to the service. If the service is in foreground mode, this signals to the service
        // that since this activity is in the foreground, the service can exit foreground mode.
        bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocationUpdatesService.ACTION_BROADCAST));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mBound) {
            // Unbind from the service. This signals to the service that this activity is no longer
            // in the foreground, and the service can respond by promoting itself to a foreground
            // service.
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        return  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
                mService.requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                setButtonsState(false);
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
// Update the buttons state depending on whether location updates are being requested.
        if (s.equals(Utils.KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES)) {
            setButtonsState(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Utils.KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES,
                    false));
        }
    }


    /**
     * Receiver for broadcasts sent by {@link LocationUpdatesService}.
     */
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationUpdatesService.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            if (location != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Utils.getLocationText(location),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setButtonsState(boolean requestingLocationUpdates) {
        if (requestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestLocationUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mRequestLocationUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what will be the correct solution for the background service for Android O.

Comment: What debugging did you try to figure out the problem?

Comment: @noogui I have put a notification which shows whenever there is location update. It stops showing after 10-12 minutes

Comment: maybe it is your phone? Did you solve this? Tested it on the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

On Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, you must declare foreground service type.

Need to add android:foregroundServiceType="location" in Service.

```
<service android:name=".LocationUpdateService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        />
```